# Unable to run django wsgi with virtual environment

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to run my django app with apache2 by using wsgi but seem to fail setting up the use of the virtual environment.

To install `mod_wsgi` I followed [Serve Python 3.7 with mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 16](https://medium.com/@garethbjohnson/serve-python-3-7-with-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-d9c7ab79e03a)
 as I'm using python3.7.

I created a virtual environment with `virtualenv -p python3.7 venv`
Using the virtual environment manually with `python manage.py runserver` works and starts the server as expected.

To start it with apache2 I configured the `my-app.conf` with:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    <Directory /home/path/to/project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/path/to/venv/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/path/to/project/server>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess project \
    python-home=/home/path/to/venv/ \
    python-path=/home/path/to/project/server/

    WSGIProcessGroup project

    WSGIScriptAlias /project /home/path/to/project/server/wsgi.py \
    process-group=example.com \
    application-group=%{GLOBAL}


    Alias /static/ /home/path/to/project/static/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

and the `my-app-ssl.conf` with:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I'm ending up getting the error: `ImportError: No module named 'django'`

which is based on the venv not set correctly. I added some code to the `wsgi.py`:

```
for k in sorted(os.environ.keys()):
        v = os.environ[k]
        print ('%-30s %s' % (k,v[:70]))
```

and can obviously see that it is not using the virtual environment compared to starting the app manually with the virtualenv.

What is wrong in my setup that it is not using the virtual environment?

Comment: Use django's guide as reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I used, as well as https://pawelzny.com/server/django/2018/02/26/the-most-complete-apache2-config-for-wsgi-django-and-drf/ but unfortunately I'm unable to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the solution. The problem was that the mod_wsgi module was built with Python3.5 and the virtual environment used Python3.7.

Manually building mod_wsgi as described here [Mod wsgi installation guide](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html) and linking the right one as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/157854/python-version-for-mod-wsgi) solved the problem